# how to send from an objective-c client to a java server?

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets

I am new to server client connection between objective c and java.
I am trying to send from the client an NSString to the java server and print it at the server here is my code.

```
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
[self initNetworkCommunication];

NSString *response  = @"testt\n";

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response     

   dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];


}
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 6789, &readStream,                           
&writeStream);
inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
 }
```

the server code:

```
  ServerSocket welcomeSocket=new Socket(6789);
  while(true){
  Socket connectionSocket=welcomeSocket.accept();
  BufferedReader inFromClient=new BufferedReader(new    
  InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
  System.out.println(inFromClient.readLine());

  }
```

Comment: on the server side nothing happens but when i stop execution at the client side, a "null" is printed on the server side.

Comment: can some one guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first glaring problem in your code appears to be that you misspelled localhost — it should be `localhost`.

You also call `initNetworkCommunication` twice. The second call will reset your IO streams to be closed, as you do not seem to call open on them after that or do anything with them, and leave the previous streams to either get deallocated or just sit around doing nothing.

Code to deal with the streams looks fine to me, but you may wish to check if the streams returned are `NULL`, as well as checking if `CFReadStreamCopyError` returns any relevant information.

Some code on your server to print a character whenever a client connects could aid you in debugging whether the issue lies with your handling of the streams, or the connection of them.

Comment: I am sorry i did notice that, it was a copy mistake but in my code localhost is spelled right and the method is only called once. Also i think there is a connection between them because when i abort the client, the server throws an exception.

Comment: found the problem. i should close outputStream after i am done.